# Delphi 10.4 - Get TXS value dynamic from property (Cast TValue to TXS Class)

Tags: delphi, soap, wsdl

Given situiation:

There is A Webapi designed on SOAP bases and delivers API functions via WSDL file.
Importing WSDL File to the Delphi Project is realy straight foreward. But inside the different Interfaces there are Tons of Propertys giving me the opportunity to read or write values. Because there also have to be the possibility to write "nillish" values, I have to use TXSString instead of String.

Now My Question: I would like to read the properties dynamic. What I got so far works well just in fact I can't get any Value out of my TValue, because it is TXSString instead of a simple String and I have no clue how to TypeCast that with a TValue.

Here is what I got so far:

```
uses
 System.TypInfo, system.Rtti; 

...

procedure TForm.GetObjectProperties(AObject: TObject; AList: TStrings);
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  rType: TRttiType;
  rProp: TRttiProperty;
  AValue: TValue;
  sVal: string;
const
  SKIP_PROP_TYPES = [tkUnknown, tkInterface];
begin
  if not Assigned(AObject) and not Assigned(AList) then
    Exit;

  ctx := TRttiContext.create;
  rType := ctx.GetType(AObject.ClassInfo);
  for rProp in rType.GetProperties do
  begin
    if (rProp.IsReadable) and not(rProp.PropertyType.TypeKind in SKIP_PROP_TYPES) then
    begin
      AValue := rProp.GetValue(AObject);
      if AValue.IsEmpty then
      begin
        sVal := 'nil';
      end
      else
      begin
        if AValue.Kind in [tkUString, tkString, tkWString, tkChar, tkWChar] then
          sVal := QuotedStr(AValue.ToString)
        else
          // Here is my part I don't know what to do TXSString(AVlaue.AsClass).NativeToXS does not work
          sVal := AValue.ToString;
      end;

      AList.Add(rProp.Name + '=' + sVal);
    end;

  end;
end;
```

The Responce looks like this:

```
name=(TXSString @ 000000000854C700)
```

So I get my Pointeraddress :) Should work I Think but the real Values would be much better :-D

Answer (score 0):

This Code works for me. Thanks to TiGü from [Delphipraxis.de](https://www.delphipraxis.net/210545-tvalue-unterschieldiche-typen-von-tremotablexs-wandeln.html#post1505641)

```
procedure {TForm.}GetObjectProperties(AObject: TObject; AList: TStrings);
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  rType: TRttiType;
  rProp, rProp2: TRttiProperty;
  rInstance: TRttiInstanceType;
  AValue: TValue;
  sVal: string;
const
  SKIP_PROP_TYPES = [tkUnknown, tkInterface];
begin
  if not Assigned(AObject) and not Assigned(AList) then
    Exit;

  ctx := TRttiContext.create;
  rType := ctx.GetType(AObject.ClassInfo);
  for rProp in rType.GetProperties do
  begin
    if (rProp.IsReadable) and not(rProp.PropertyType.TypeKind in SKIP_PROP_TYPES) then
    begin
      if rProp.PropertyType.TypeKind = tkClass then
      begin
        rInstance := rProp.PropertyType.AsInstance;
        AValue := rProp.GetValue(AObject);
        if AValue.IsInstanceOf(TRemotableXS) then
        begin
          sVal := TRemotableXS(AValue.AsObject).NativeToXS;
        end;
      end else
      begin
        AValue := rProp.GetValue(AObject);
        if AValue.IsEmpty then
        begin
          sVal := 'nil';
        end
        else
        begin
          if AValue.Kind in [tkUString, tkString, tkWString, tkChar, tkWChar] then
            sVal := QuotedStr(AValue.ToString)
          else
            sVal := AValue.ToString;
        end;
      end;

      AList.Add(rProp.Name + '=' + sVal);
    end;
  end;
end;

type
  TMyPropFullClass = class
  private
    FSomeString: TXSstring;
  public
    constructor Create;
    property SomeString: TXSstring read FSomeString;
  end;

constructor TMyPropFullClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FSomeString := TXSstring.Create;
  FSomeString.XSToNative('Hello World');
end;

initialization
var MyData: TMyPropFullClass := TMyPropFullClass.Create;
var MyList: TStringList := TStringList.Create;
  GetObjectProperties(MyData, MyList);
  OutputDebugString(PChar(MyList.Text));
```